# ipatool failed with an exception

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm exporting an archive for enterprise deployment and I'm getting an exception from `ipatool`. How can I work around this?

`` 2016-03-28 18:37:15 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error    Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass> ``

Answer (score 20):

I first noticed this in Xcode 7.3 but it may well have existed long before this. Some of our 3rd party libraries don't support Bitcode so we have it turned off in our project settings. However, when I was exporting for an enterprise distribution, there was a check box (that was checked) asking if I wanted to "Rebuild from bitcode"; unchecking this box solved the problem for me. This check box is in the screen after "Preparing Archive".

[image]